# rsync exclude based on file size?

Tags: regular-expression, rsync

Is it possible to exclude files in `rsync` over a certain size (e.g. over 250 MB)?

And what if I also want to exclude hidden files?

How would I exclude all hidden files or directories (those that match ".*") as well as files (not directories) that are greater than 250 MB (whether hidden or not)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`rsync --max-size=... --exclude '.*'`

**Edit 1:**

Quoting from the man page:

> --max-size=SIZE
>
> This tells rsync to avoid transferring any file that is larger than the specified SIZE. The SIZE value can be suffixed with a string to  indicate a
>   size multiplier, and may be a fractional value (e.g. "--max-size=1.5m").
>
> This  option  is a transfer rule, not an exclude, so it doesn’t affect the data that goes into the file-lists, and thus it doesn’t affect deletions.
>   It just limits the files that the receiver requests to be transferred.
>
> The suffixes are as follows: "K" (or "KiB") is a kibibyte (1024), "M" (or "MiB") is a mebibyte  (1024*1024),  and  "G"  (or  "GiB")  is  a  gibibyte
>   (1024*1024*1024). If you want the multiplier to be 1000 instead of 1024, use "KB", "MB", or "GB". (Note: lower-case is also accepted for all values.) Finally, if the suffix ends in either "+1" or "-1", the value will be offset by one byte in the indicated direction.
>
> Examples: --max-size=1.5mb-1 is 1499999 bytes, and --max-size=2g+1 is 2147483649 bytes.

Comment: can you give an example of how to specify max-size? Is this correct? `rsync -avz --max-size=250MB --exclude '.*' ...`

Comment: @MountainX See edit.

Comment: I guess it is like `rsync -auvz  --max-size=250M --exclude '.*' /home/me/Music/ /home/me/Box/Music` I found the details of K M and G here http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/rsync-command-examples/